# Storing a non-json object to a file and then retreiving it?

Tags: json, node.js

Consider an object
var obj = [
1,
2,
3,
"temp":"value"
];

You can create this so don't worry about that.
Now you want to store this in a file so you will use `JSON.stringify()` and then store it in a file.

But as you can see the above object is not json so stringify would result in somewhat like this:
[1,2,3] here the temp_data field is missing.

Now I need to store this object in a file then retrieve it again ... Any suggestions?

Comment: Store and retrieve it as a String, write a parser? Or modify your data format to allow it to be serializable in JSON?

Answer (score 0):

`var obj = [ 1, 2, 3, "temp":"value" ];` this is not valid javascript, you cannot create this, but this is valid:`var obj = [ 1, 2, 3, {"temp":"value"} ];`

Because your talking about an object I assume that you mean to put the brackets there. With brackets there is no problem and it can be converted:

```
var obj = [ 1, 2, 3, {"temp":"value"} ];
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) === obj // will return true
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) === obj` will **NOT** return true. See [this article](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html)